# Alternative way of saying "we largely follow the account of...."

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I find myself writing the following phrase over and over again in my thesis:

> In the following subsection we largely follow the account laid out by Smith in [1].

I am looking for alternative ways to express that, in a particular subsection, I use the work of Smith and follow his account on the subject.

What are some other ways of saying this?

Comment: Look for synonyms of ***largely***, if that's what you'd like to replace. Asking to rephrase the whole sentence is off-topic for ELU. Maybe you should check if it's acceptable in [writers.se]

Comment: In the following subsection we draw mainly from the account given by Smith in [1].

Answer (score 1):

You could use *"the [investigation/redaction/account] in this subsection is [synonymes of largely] along the lines of [the one in] Smith [1]"*.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative ways of saying: In the following subsection we largely follow the account laid out by Smith in [1].

> In the following subsection we explore the account laid out by
>   Smith in [1]...

or,

> In the following subsection we turn to the account laid out by
>   Smith in [1]...

or,

> The account laid out by Smith in [1] is pertinent here...

or,

> In the following subsection I elucidate the account laid out by
>   Smith in [1]...

Edit in relation to comments:

Other ways of expressing "the account laid out by"

> "the account articulated by..."
>
> "the case made by..."
>
> "the theory as discussed by..." (if it pertains to a theory)
>
> "the contribution of..."

Comment: +1 This is a useful response, I don't know why someone downvoted it. What about alternative ways of saying "the account laid out by" ?

Comment: What is the subject?

Comment: It's an undergraduate math thesis, @Gary.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas have edited to give you some ideas.

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated, @Gary.